# C# - Inheritance from method to method within a class?

Tags: c#, oop

Is it possible to inherit a method within a class?
Or does it always need to be parent class inheriting child class?

For example:

A class called **make_chart**

Has:

```
public void style_Chart(Chart chartName,....)
{

}
```

Can I then inherit style_Chart into a new method called style_Chart2?

Something like this:

```
public void style_Chart2: style_Chart(new parameter)
{

}
```

Comment: interesting...have you seen a language where such constructs are possible?

Comment: No - I rarely use most parts of OO - but thought it might be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the same type, you would just invoke it:

```
public void style_Chart2()
{
    style_Chart({some parameters});
}
```

If you are dealing with sublasses, you might also consider `virtual` / `base` / `override`. There *is* a chaining syntax, but it only applies to constructors ( `: base(...)` or `: this(...)`).

Comment: Thanks Marc - The simplest solutions are always the best.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading)

```
public void style_Chart(Chart chartName) {

}

public void style_Chart(Chart chartName, new parameter) { 
    style_Chart(chartName);
    //now do things with new parameter
}
```